# Will Custom Printed Luggage with QR Codes Confuse Airport Scanners?

Tags: luggage, airport-security

I'm planning to order custom printed luggage to promote a business, and I'm considering incorporating a QR code for easy access to more information. I've read a [question on StackExchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17590/does-leaving-mini-bag-tag-stickers-on-your-luggage-confuse-airport-bagging-handl) about issues with multiple stickers causing confusion at airports, but those stickers are not what I'm referring to.

My concern is whether a printed QR code on luggage could potentially interfere with or confuse airport scanners. Specifically, is there a chance this could become an issue as airports update their systems from barcode to QR code scanning technology?

Thank you for any insights you may have on this topic!

Comment: *"is there a chance this could become an issue as airports update their systems from barcode to QR code scanning technology"*  - It is impossible to give a definitive answer on what may or may not pose problems for future technology. - I expect that by design it ***should not***  pose a problem, but theory vs real-world :  that doesn't exclude for example an implementation flaw and gives no guarantee that it ***never will*** pose a problem. (Let alone a  well-meaning person deciding that it might pose a problem and rejecting your luggage.)

Comment: I think your question is too technical for this site. IATA, ICAO, and other organization should have documents on tags. Machines may distinguish it (because of content). Manual scanning by baggage handler is different, it may be more error prone (so delay on baggage, or less careful handling of them: do not mess with baggage handlers). Make sure it clear for human (machine will know it anyway). I think barcodes has problems now (reuse of same number is too frequent, so problem in case of delays).

Comment: I see this as a potential issue only if the scanning is done automatically, rather than point-and-shoot by a person. The machine will scan your QR, notice that it doesn't fit their schema, then trigger a human response action. This might make your luggage miss your flight.

Comment: Maybe you should consider NFC, or even RFID, if the main point of the QR is internal tracking. You don't seem to be seeking that, but other readers might.

Comment: [Frank's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/131549/27701) on your linked question seems to cover what I said. It might send your luggage to the reject belt. I think you'd be fine with only one QR code.